# How do I fix Google Chrome's latest new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I've just updated to the latest Google Chrome Dev build, and they've changed from the annoying-but-ok new tab page to an ugly and less usable page.

On the old one, nine thumbnails was not enough, and now they've restricted it to eight.

There's an empty "Tips and Suggestions" box which I wouldn't want even if it had stuff in; they've added Recent Downloads - on the *rare* occasions when I need that, I'll hit Ctrl-J to open the Downloads tab; and the site-specific search box on the right has now gone!

**Is there a way to get the old new tab page back, or a plugin to provide a superior one?**

*Update:*
I launch Chrome by pressing Win+R and entering "chrome" - I have a shortcut on the Path with a Target of `"C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --old-new-tab-page` and whilst double-clicking this shortcut brings up the previous new tab page, using the keyboard method results in the old one.

**How do I get it working via the Run box?**
(*Without* using a batch file, which slows things down too much.)

*Update 2:*
***GRRR!*** Now they've gone and stopped the `--old-new-tab-page` parameter from working at all!
I hate this new version of the page that they're forcing upon us - can anyone provide a method to get rid of it and get the decent page back?

Answer (score 4):

If you append:

`--old-new-tab-page`

to your Chrome shortcut, it will revert the New Tab page to the original 3x3 layout with the Searches and Bookmarks on the right-hand side. Just tested it now on mine, works perfectly.

Comment: This only appears to work for clicked shortcuts. If I do start>run "chrome" to launch it (with a suitably modified shortcut on the path) it uses the new tab page still.

Comment: Ah, that's a slightly different question then, I see you have updated the text. I'll look into it...

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `--old-new-tab-page` to the command line arguments of the program, like a desktop shortcut. For universal support, you will most likely need to edit the registry to change the way Chrome is started by Windows.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\chrome.exe\shell\open\command` is the relevant registry key.

Comment: Same as other comment - even with the reg key it doesn't work if I do start>run "chrome" to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm cross-posting [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/688555/140956) from a similar question:

You can revert the old New Tab Page by following [my workaround](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=326788#c11):

1. Install the [New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) extension
2. Set the URL in options to: **chrome-internal://newtab/** or **chrome://apps**